# What is main:Object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error:

``` NoMethodError: undefined method ``where' for main:Object ```

My question is, what is main:Object?

Answer (score 1):

It is the default context; the `self` when you are not inside a `class` or a `module`.